# execv() not working properly

Tags: c, execv

I am having a weird issue. For homework I am creating my own basic bash script, but when running execv() to run my cp command, it does not work. It works with ls and groups, but not cp. I messed around with my cp program to isolate the error and it is indeed the execv command.

```
void ls(char** array)
{
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
                execv("./ls",array);
        }
        else
        {       
                waitpid(pid,0,0);
        }

}

void cp(char** array)
{
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
                execv("./cp",array);
        }
        else
        {
                waitpid(pid,0,0);
        }
}

void groups(char** array)
{
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
                execv("./groups",array);
        }
        else
        {
                waitpid(pid,0,0);
        }
}

int input()
{
        char buffer[128];
        char * str;
        char * str1;
        char * str2;
        char * str3;
        char *name;
        int i = 0;
        int num;
        int words = 1;
        name = getlogin();
        printf("%s --->", name);
        int result = scanf("%[^\n]",buffer);
        getchar();
        char **array;
        if (result > 0)
        {
                for (int i = 0; buffer[i]!='\0'; i++)
                {
                        if (buffer[i] == ' ' || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\t')
                        {
                                words++;
                        }
                }

                array = malloc(words * sizeof(char*));
                array[0] = strtok(buffer, " ");
                for(int w = 1; w < words; w++)
                {
                        array[w] = strtok(NULL, " ");
                }
                if (words == 1)
                {
                        array[1] = '\0';
                }

        }
        str = strstr(array[0], "ls");
        str1 = strstr(array[0], "cp");
        str2 = strstr(array[0], "groups");
        str3 = strstr(array[0], "exit");
        if (str != NULL)
        {
                ls(array);
                free(array);
        }
        else if (str1 != NULL)
{
                cp(array);
                free(array);
        }
        else if (str2 != NULL)
        {
                groups(array);
                free(array);
        }
        else if (str3 != NULL)
        {
                num = 0;
                free(array);
                return num;
        }
        else
        {
                printf("Incorrect command\n");
        }
        num = 1;
        return num;
```

I feel that this snippet should be fine. My code gets to the execv correctly, it just doesn't execute it for some reason. ls and groups works fine, but cp does not. My main just calls input

Comment: Have you tried adding some debug output, error checking? What's in `array`? What does 'does not work' mean?

Comment: Checked that `cp` is in the current working directory

Comment: yes I have, cp is in the correct directory. By not working I mean that it prints nothing at all when the cp command is called. Basically the user will type cp [file] [destination], and when I hit enter it does not do anything at all. When execv does return -1 indicating it didn't execute properly

Comment: What's in array? What if fork/execv/waitpid fails? What if waitpid succesfully returns because the child changed status but didn't die? Why are you trying to make StackOverflow run your C code as JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry about the javascript thing, I have not really figured out how to use this website properly when it comes to posting code. Array has whatever the user inputs, for testing purposes it is array[0] = cp, array[1] = testfile1.txt, array[2] = Documents. I didn't add any error checking to fork/execv/waitpid because they generally always work. I am learning now that I should always have error checking

Comment: Are you sure you have an executable file "cp" in you are working. Usually cp resides in "/bin". I guess that you want to move a copy of testfile.txt to a directory called Documents. In this case you should use array[0] = cp, array[1] = testfile1.txt and array[2] = Documents/     Don't forget the backslah "/"

Comment: Are the directories in array absolute paths and not pointing to files in /bin

Comment: You really need to post code other people can run that matches yours - right now you have a bunch of people playing a guessing game instead of helping you or someone else.

Comment: it is a custom cp program, and I have it taking care of the absolute paths and all that.

Comment: _" execv does return -1"_ Ok, so what does `errno` have to say?

Comment: it is giving me bad address, sorry everyone I know this is really frustrating for you. I am slowly learning how to use this website.

Comment: Perhaps you should try this with the real cp. Yours might be broken confusing things further.

Comment: tested and same error, I also tested it with my cp program by itself by calling it in bash and it worked fine. I think it might be an issue that I don't have enough space allocated

Comment: I'll edit my post and just post my entire code, I originally didn't want to do that because it is so huge, but looks like that may have to be what I do

Comment: Perhaps change `./cp` to `/bin/echo` to find out what is happening

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: first problem with the posted code:  the function: `fork()` has three different return indications:  returned value <0 means an error occurred  returned value ==0 means the child is executing.  returned value >0 means the parent is executing.  The posted code is missing the checking for the error condition

Comment: this: ` array[0] = cp, array[1] = testfile1.txt, array[2] = Documents.` is missing the final parameter, which must be a NULL

Answer (score 3):

My guess based on the limited information is that the array that is sent as a parameter only contains one of the two things you would like to send to `cp`. Verify that you send both source and destination to `cp` by printing the array before calling `execv`. Also make sure that the arrays last element is a null pointer.

Comment: it is getting the source and destination correctly. I also went into my cp program and had it print out a statement on the first line and it did not do that.

Comment: Verify that there is a null pointer as the last element of the array.

Comment: Well this is interesting, when trying to do so it is now giving me a segmentation fault

Comment: Have you allocated space for the extra null pointer? There is a nifty tool called valgrind which helps you find seg-faults and memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
char* args[] = { "/bin/cp", "/etc/passwd", "passwd-copy", 0 };
pid_t pid; 
if(0>(pid=fork())){
    perror(0); 
    return -1;
}
if(0==pid){
    execv(args[0], args);
    perror(0);
    _exit(127);
}
siginfo_t info;
if(0>waitid(P_PID, pid, &info, WEXITED)){
    perror(0);
    return -1;
}
return info.si_status;
```

Comment: other than 0 is NOT a NULL, (although the `implicit conversion` feature of C might save your program).   the function `perror()` expects a pointer as a parameter, not an integer.  The array 'args{}` needs to have the last entry be NULL, not 0

Comment: @user3629249 Actually, `0` is fully standard compliant value of the `NULL` macro, as is `(void*)0` . Sometimes you need casts, like in `execlp("foo", "foo", "bar", (char*)0);` but not in any of the contexts above (provided that `stdio.h` is included and the prototype of `perror` is brought along with it).

Comment: @user3629249 `perror(0)` works the sem as `perror("")` -- no prefix, no colon, just a stringified `errno`. I think allowing the null pointer in `perror` is  bad design (as is the whole `perror` function) but since it's available and people use it, I might as well.